# Laravel 5.1: Registration page routing

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I am developing a registration process using Laravel. But I am feeling a problem. I'm using the implicit controller

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

My registration anchor tag link to the 'auth/registration'

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="auth/register">
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>  Register
</a>
```

When I first time click the link, It works properly and show my intended page. But when I go to my intended register page and click again the link it shows an error and also my browser address bar show the link is this way -

```
http://localhost:8000/auth/auth/register
```

And give me an error message - "Controller method not found."

But when I clicked the link first time the browser address bar showed the link in this way -

```
http://localhost:8000/auth/register
```

and that's time the link worked properly but when I click it second time on the register page it doesn't work properly and show an error message.

Could you please someone let me know how can I fix it?

Comment: probably need forward slash on href /auth

Answer (score 0):

use url() method

```
 <a href="{{ url('/auth/register') }}">register</a>
```

instead of  href="auth/register" I think it is  laravel 5